# Adding audio to a video file using ffmpeg lengthen the first video frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, duration

My file "TestVideo.avi" has only one video stream and no audio stream and its time_base=1/25
The first video frames of this file are :

```
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size= 12172  pts=0  bets=0   keyFrame=1
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  4886  pts=1  bets=1   keyFrame=0
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  5732  pts=2  bets=2   keyFrame=0
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  5073  pts=3  bets=3   keyFrame=0
```

Then I add audio using this command :
ffmpeg -i TestVideo.avi -i TestAudio.wav -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -b:a 192k Result.avi

Then the first video frames of "Result.avi" are :

```
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size= 12172  pts=0  bets=0   keyFrame=1
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  4886  pts=2  bets=2   keyFrame=0
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  5732  pts=3  bets=3   keyFrame=0
pkt_duration=1   pkt_size=  5073  pts=4  bets=4   keyFrame=0
```

ffmpeg lengthen the first frame and I don't understand why.
Can you help me please ?

The "TestVideo.avi" duration is 10 seconds, like the "TestAudio.wav" file.
The "TestAudio.wav" file is "normal" : 16 bits and 44100Hz.

Thank you.

Comment: Likely due to the priming sample of MP3. Encode to `pcm_s16le` and see if it still happens.

Comment: You are right ! Using pcm_s16le, the first frame duration is well encoded ! So now... How can I do to use mp3 audio encoding and having a good first frame duration encoding ?